(re)mount network drive after password change
We have several Linux servers mounting a network drive
with a line in /etc/fstab like this one:
//10.10.1.10/net_folder/local_folder cifs _netdev,credentials=/etc/security/user_credentials
The drive is mounted
using some user credentials stored in the file user_credentials. 
Soon we will change the password for this user and update the file. After the password has been changed,
we would like to do the mount again
in order to use the new credentials. 
We would like to execute the mount without rebooting the servers. 
Which is the best option?
Option 1:
mount -o remount /local_folder

Option 2:
umount /local_folder
mount -av

Some say that mount -a would be enough,
but some others say that the command ignores already mounted drives,
so I thought to unmount before. 
I also found that just partitions with the noauto option are ignored.
Or maybe there is a better option not mentioned here.

I would use an automount instead of the static mount.
